# Where did I make the mistake in the Fourier transform?

Tags: fourier-transform

$$ \begin{align}
X(f) & = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t)e^{-j2\pi ft}dt & \\
     & = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t)\left(e^{-j2\pi} \right)^{ft}dt & \;\;\mathrm{where}\; e^{-j2\pi}=1 \\
     & = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t) (1)^{ft}\; dt, &\;\;\mathrm{but}\ \; 1^{ft} \; \mathrm{is\;always } \; 1 \\
     & = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t) dt, &\;\;\mathrm{i.e.\; the\; area\; under} \; x(t) \; \mathrm{from\; -\infty\; to\;  +\infty}  
\end{align}
$$

But this seems very weird!!!

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[See this Wikipedia article.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Complex_exponents_with_a_positive_real_base)

You can only multiply exponents if they are real. Let's look at the example of $f\cdot t = 1/4$

$$ e^{-j2\pi\frac{1}{4}} = e^{-j\frac{\pi}{2}} = -j \neq 1$$